# Dask worker persistent variables

Tags: python, dask

Is there a way with dask to have a variable that can be retrieved from one task to another. I mean a variable that I could lock in the worker and then retrieve in the same worker when i execute another task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workers themselves are just Python processes, so you could do tricks with `globals()`.

However, it is probably cleaner to emit values and pass these between tasks.  Dask retains the right to rerun functions and run them on different machines, so depending on global state or worker-specific state can easily get you into trouble.

Comment: Thx for the answer but the globals tricks seems not working. I tried to run this code in my workers: `i = 0
def engine(cmd):
    global i
    print('i is :%d'%(i))
    i = i + 1`. But the counter remains to 0

Comment: Yeah, I recommend not using globals

Comment: Thx for your answers i'll try to handle that differently so.